# "Forget" followed by a gerund

Tags: verbs, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

Since "forget" followed by a gerund refers to the past, which one of the following sentences is correct?

> " I forgot to lock the door."
>
> "I forget locking the door."
>
> "I forget having locked the door."

Comment: Is there any reason you used the past tense *forgot* only in the first sentence?

Comment: The first option is OK, the second isn't usable, and the third is not great English but would get past some censors. Other options would be "I can't remember if I locked the door", "I can't remember locking the door".

Comment: @Rathony I didn't use the past tense in the last two sentences, because I think the gerund expresses a past situation.

Comment: I see. I just wanted to clarify it as you started the question with "forget".

Comment: @ralph.m How come second one is unusable?

Comment: @Grizzly I think he meant "it isn't common" by "isn't usable".

Comment: @Rathony Hmmmm. Not common. Might be. However, gerund and infitinive after forget clearly has two different meanings. Gerund; you forgot somehing you did. Infinitive; you forgot that you need to do something.

Comment: @Grizzly That's the reason why it could be less common. You *habitually* forget to lock the door. You *habitually* forget whether you locked the door or not.

Comment: I can't find the duplicate, but I'm sure there is one. [Wiktionary has an article on English catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs) (ie those taking an untensed complement) that explains the difference between "I forgot to lock the door" and "I forgot locking the door." I'd say your other two sentences are a better choice for stating a common occurrence ("I often forget locking the door [even though I've never yet actually left it unlocked]")....

Comment: For a one-off, 'I've forgotten whether I locked the door' is the natural choice, though 'I forget locking the door' _is_ used – but I'd say _rarely_ in situations where there isn't fairly strong evidence that you must have. 'Look – your door is locked. And nobody but you has a key!' ...

Comment: All three are correct.

Comment: @curiousdannii +1. Your comment could be the right answer for the question.

Comment: @Rathony Though the question should be closed for lack of research rather than being answer.

Comment: @curiousdannii You've just saved me a lot of work trawling through possible duplicates. Thank you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unless a question gives reason to doubt whether a sentence is grammatical (such as some quoted grammatical rule) all questions asking whether X is correct should be closed. :)

Comment: @curiousdannii I can't agree with that. Quirk and Svartvik moot a five-point scale of acceptability for sentences etc. This means that different (well educated) Anglophones have different perceptions on some usages, so here 'rules' are more or less arbitrary. And changeable. And sometimes, the 'rules' (still often inadequate, of course) are just not easy to find even when someone _has_ arrogated some.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree with you, however, I closevoted it first and retracted it later as it looked related with English Language and Usage. Usually "which is correct" type of question is not OK here, but I think the OP wants to clarify the differences in the three sentences rather than seeking any advice in grammatical correctness.

Comment: @Edwin Well that would be okay IMO, if you gave reason to think that there's a difference between UK and US English for example. But this question doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

What's really going on here is that there are two different meanings of *forget*, which have different subcategorisation frames. They typically have different restrictions on tense, but that is a consequence of their semantics.

The normal *forget*, meaning *no longer have the memory of an experience* takes a noun phrase, including a gerund phrase. *I have forgotten locking the door* = *I no longer have in my memory the experience of locking the door*. This sense is usually in the past, especially a perfect form; it can be future ("You will forget ever seeing me"), but even then it is more often perfect ("You will forget ever having seen me").

The other sense, *omit doing something that was intended or expected* also takes a noun phrase, but if it is verbal, it is usually an infinitive with "to". This form can occur in any tense.

So the primary difference is semantic, which has a consequent effect on tense; but does also affect the syntactic choice of object.

Comment: Typo edited. Sorry.

Comment: And to 'forget about' can have either meaning (_and_ the deliberate putting out of mind).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: True, it can.

Answer (score 2):

*"I forgot to lock the door."*

Correct and quite common usage, and meaning you failed to do it, not whether you remember doing it or not.

*"I forget locking the door."*

Grammatically correct (just), but stilted and not often used (more usual would be: "I forget whether I locked the door (or not).").

*"I forget having locked the door."*

Also grammatically correct, but also a bit stilted and not that common as usage, and again, "I forget whether I locked the door (or not)." would be more usual.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the second sentence. *I forget locking the door* is the speaker complaining that (s)he forgets that (s)he has to lock the door. Not, as you suggested `I forget whether I locked the door (or not)`

Comment: @Darshan Chaudhary Though that would be the normal interpretation, it _could_ be used after you have just been reminded (by someone or events). Look up the Wiktionary example.

Comment: @Darshan Chaudhary: I can't agree with the interpretation of the second sentence, or at least if that is the intended meaning, it is very stilted and unnatural English expression. The preferred way of achieving the meaning you are describing, would be: "I (always) forget to lock the door."